# How to open fixed paper ceiling lamp

Tags: light-fixture

The bulb needs changing but I have no idea how to open this, I tried twisting it but I am afraid it will break. It feels like it is somehow attached to the hanging bulb, but I might be wrong.

Nothing "opens", it's all one piece, glued together.[image]

Comment: If it is very lightweight it might just be held by friction so try just pulling down, maybe with twisting. Alternatively you might have to twist or push up and twist.

Comment: It is pretty light. I am afraid that the lamp is fixed on the bulb and by twisting it I might damage the cables holding the bulb socket. I will try pulling down on it though.

Comment: Where did you find this?  I.e., what country, and is it in a residence or commercial location?

Comment: @feetwet Netherlands, private apartment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I expected. It is held by magnets, you just have to pull down on it and it will come off. Twisting it is a bad idea as it rotates the entire lamp block and wires.